# Best Way to Show Helpful hints for First Time Site Visitors RoR/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, usability

I'm looking for some advice to show tooltips/animations for first time site visitors.  Any recommendations for existing plugins either for rails or jquery?  I couldn't find any tutorials or examples out there.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use cookies to find out if this is the first time someone visits your site.
checkout http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?t=37905.
Also you can integrate it with some nice plugins for better UI. check out http://code.google.com/p/submodal/ It looks nice!
UPDATE: Found another working sample at http://bignosebird.com/js/h24.shtml